# ACF Gallery & mqTranslate, Title and Description not displaying in other languages

Tags: media

I am using mqTranslate and ACF Gallery to build a gallery. Below is the code.

```
<?php $images = get_field('home_slides', 'options'); ?>
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
            <li>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                <p><?php echo $image['title']; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $image['description']; ?></p>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I display Title and Description in other languages? Since both [:en] and `<!--:en-->Title<!--:-->`
 are not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo qtrans_useCurrentLanguageIfNotFoundUseDefaultLanguage("<!--:en-->Hi<!--:--><!--:zh-->你好<!--:-->"); ?>
```

If you try the above line in English and Chinese, you'll see "Hi" and "你好".